# How to Increment a number in the name of a file everytime the Batch file is run

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using CommandCam, a software which takes a photo from specified webcam everytime it is run. I am using it to take a photo whenever my computer starts up, but what the software does is it overwrites the previous image taken with the same name. So I created a .bat file that checks if `image.bmp` exists, save the new image file as `image_1.bmp`. However it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried to use `GOTO` but it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
if exist image.bmp (goto existing) else (goto nonexisting)

:nonexisting
set /A imgnum = 0
.\CommandCam.exe
exit /B

:existing
set /A imgnum+=1
.\CommandCam.exe /filename image_%imgnum%.bmp
exit /B
```

The first time the .bat is run, it works as expected. A `image.bmp` file is created. And next time the .bat is run, it works too, A `image_1.bmp` is created. But the third and so on time the .bat is run, it doesn't work and just overwrites `image_1.bmp` . Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file should check `image.bmp`, `image1.bmp`, `image2.bmp`, etc. until it finds a non-existing file.  Like this:

```py
@echo off
setlocal
set imgnum=
if not exist image.bmp goto nonexisting
set imgnum=0

:existing
set /A imgnum += 1
if exist image%imgnum%.bmp goto existing

:nonexisting
echo >image%imgnum%.bmp
endlocal
```

The `setlocal`/`endlocal` make sure the environment isn't left with `imagnum` set to some value.  I just used `echo` to create the file for testing.